# Настройка CMS через php

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, что подразумевает собой настройка и доработка CMS через php. Я новичок в php, а среди вакансий для разработчиков php очень часто требуется настройка CMS, подскажите пожалуйста где можно найти обучающие материалы к этой теме.

Comment: Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос, для начала нужно освоить PHP, и только после этого осваивать CMS с использованием PHP, и это не гарантирует вам то, что вы сможете настраивать CMS. Как правило уже битые волки, и то допускают ошибки безопасности, представьте себе, что компания заказала установку и настройку OS сервера, сайта работающем на CMS и PHP кода, после чего сайт взломали , базу слили, как думаете кто отвечать будет ???

Comment: Ну это понятно, но если у вас есть материалы по настройке CMS  через php то  скиньте ссылку, или укажите пожалуйста где искать

Comment: ваш вопрос очень обобщённый, вам необходимо знать php как таблицу умножения, а уже потом смотреть вакансии. 
Простое задание для студента первого курса: сохраните данные из формы регистрации в базу sql, и сохраните cookies пользователю в браузер, чтоб при следующем обращении пользователь авторизовался автоматически с использованием сессии.  После выполнения задачи вы поймёте, что система управления сайтом как правило состоит и тысяч подобных функций.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Что такое CMS?](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BC)
2. [Что такое PHP?](http://php.net/manual/ru/intro-whatis.php)
3. [Что такое SQL?](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL)
4. [Что такое HTML?](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML)
5. [Что такое JavaScript?](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)
6. [Что такое Ajax?](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX)
7. [Что такое XML?](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)
8. [Что такое Json?](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

Для разбора, редактирования, правки, написания CMS вы не просто должны знать, что это такое, а абсолютно свободно обладать каждым пунктом, и это только вершина айсберга.